# About permission in S3 file transfer

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm using S3TransferManager-Sample to do testing. I created the Cognito and setup the IAM and change the constants.swift file at last.I have no problem to upload but failed to download. The error message is:

> download failed: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=1
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain
>   error 1.)" UserInfo=0x7f8cd658a5a0
>   {HostId=d4yLouhlYmGn4s1Zp54+EOsZQEy2bVEGNs5XIa8pMxerJggANV/9Zb82c1QtF/5Hsn5KqYXGqdw=,
>   Message=Access Denied, Code=AccessDenied, RequestId=A1966393EAC3F15F}]

Here is my setting for the role:

[image]

[image]

My setting in the S3 bucket:

[image]

Of course when I added "Everyone" to allow "List" permission, I can download. But what is the purpose for Cognito then? Thanks

Comment: Actually I got permission deny even if I add "Everyone" with List,View permission for the bucket. I have to add permission to individual file so that users are able to view the file. What could be wrong in my setting?

Comment: In another word, how am I suppose to setup all the files inside the bucket accessible? Instead of setting up them individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things to note in your question:

1. You've set your unauth role to only allow only read-only access. The sample does not use authentication, so please make sure to update the unauth role to have full access.
2. The credentials provider caches credentials it fetches for up to one hour. You may want to either until the previous credentials expire or explicitly call the refresh method on the credentials provider to force the new policy to apply.

Comment: I'll have a try. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue. I thought only the "auth role" mattered, but actually it's the "unauth" role that mattered in the case of my iOS app uploading images to s3.