# AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 on iOS Swift While trying to upload Image/pdf

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload pdf file or image file to AWSS3 bucket but I am getting **AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2** error. Please note I already have checked **region** and it is correct. Also I have verified that I am using correct **accessKey** and **secretKey** I also have visited below mentioned links with no luck:

- (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/2553.)
- (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/604)
- (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/420)
- (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/103)
- ([Upload image to S3 with Amazon Educate Starter Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289481/upload-image-to-s3-with-amazon-educate-starter-account))
- ([About permission in S3 file transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712943/about-permission-in-s3-file-transfer))
- ([Swift iOS: Unable to Upload Image to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058065/swift-ios-unable-to-upload-image-to-aws-s3))
- ([AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456903/awss3transferutilityerrordomain-code-2-on-ios))

My code to upload file is below:

```
let credentials = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: “accessKey” , secretKey: “secretKey”)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.APSouth1 , credentialsProvider: credentials)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = { (task, progress) in
       DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // Update a progress bar
             print("Task: \(task)")
             print("Progress: \(progress)")
        })
   }
 var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
 completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
       if let error = error {
          CommonLoader.hide()
          SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: error.localizedDescription)
          return
       }
                // Do stuff after success
    })
 }
let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
// contentType —-> “image/jpeg” for images && “application/pdf” for pdf files
transferUtility.uploadData(data, bucket: s3BucketName, key: remoteName, contentType: contentType, expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                // error case
            }
            else {
                if !task.isFaulted && task.result != nil {
                    // success case
                }
            }
            
            return nil
            
}
```

Comment: Excellent Question i was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of search and reading documentation I am able to solve this issue.
In my case there were two strange things, one with same credentials and bucket on **Android** it was working.
But on **iOS** exactly same code was working in Dubai but not in Pakistan.
I solved the issue by just adding the region to project info.plist file as mentioned below:

- Please note in my case region was **ap-south-1** but you need to put it here yours, you can check region from [Amazon S3 Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) and then find corresponding region value to use in your info.plist. Hope this will help someone and save time. Happy coding. cheers!

```
<key>S3TransferUtility</key>
<dict>
   <key>Default</key>
   <dict>
        <key>Region</key>
        <string>"ap-south-1"</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I am getting this error:

`
Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={Server=AmazonS3, Transfer-Encoding=Identity, Connection=close, Content-Type=application/xml, Date=Wed, 04 May 2022 13:14:48 GMT, x-amz-request-id=C8MP74N9Y, x-amz-id-2=ZMQ12OFa2qXS0ju+9vaN/p2DvUxLo/dvaqgKxrzC+LowFZyIAHo=})

`

   
Could you please help me out... I tried out your solution but didn't worked.

Comment: @Kudos did you solved this error? I am also facing the same error.

Comment: Yeah I solved it recently. Actually My DB Name was wrong. You know I thought My DB name should be `Todo` but it was actually somewthing `Todo-242hsudfhs-afs2734`, which was automatically created by Ampilfy. So when I used this long name of DB it fixed. Also Look into this issue I reported and solved `https://github.com/soto-project/soto/issues/595`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure access key is not deleted on AWS IAM console and verify correct access and secret key added in code.

   AWS IAM Menu -> Security Credentials -> Access Keys

   Access keys section have the access and secret keys and that should be added in code.
2. Make sure you have set correct region in the AWS configuration in code.

[image]